# Active SignalR socket connection in VUE SPA components

Tags: websocket, vuejs3, signalr, vue-router, single-page-application

I have a Vue 3 SPA application using vue-router. I have set up a SignalR socket in a separate file called websocket.js. Initially, when I land on the /login page and authenticate, I receive a token that is then set in the socket.header. However, the connection is only established on the login page, and when I import the socket on other pages (components), I see in the debug that it is disconnected.

However, after refreshing the page with F5, everything works as intended. Can you please advise if there is a way to avoid this refresh and, after authentication, navigate to the /lists route using `router.push('/lists')` with an active socket connection?

```
 // websocket.js
const socket = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl(state.socket_addr, {headers: {'Authorization': state.token} })
.build()

async function start() {
    socket.headers = {'Authorization': state.token}
    console.log(socket.headers)
    try {
        await socket.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
}
start()
export default socket

    // gloabal.js
const state = reactive(
    {
        isAuthenticated: localStorage.getItem('user_token'), 
        token: 'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('user_token') 
})
export default state
```

The console.log(socket.headers) displays the modified and correct header, indicating that the issue is not with the globals or setting the headers, but with something else...
The code for the socket is taken from the developer's site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

In details of this problem